# Java Why am I getting a NullPointerException while instantiating my array

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I am new to programming and don't get why the program gives me a run time error for NullPointerException when I have tried initializing n, numInt, and arrayMenu. None of which seem to work. The program's job is to gather a set of random integers to store in an array and allow the user to pick which sort to choose from. Thanks for reading.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class VariousSortsHS
{
    private static int[] arrayMenu;
    private static Random generator;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class VariousSortsHS.
     */
    public VariousSortsHS(int n) //The error starts here
    {                                
        arrayMenu = new int[n];  //I don't get why it says null in the array when
                                 //i am initializing the length of the array to n
        /*Assigns a random number between 0 too 100.*/
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        {
            int temp = generator.nextInt(100);
            arrayMenu[n] = temp;
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Selection Sort method.
     */
    public static void selection(int n)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < arrayMenu.length - 1; i++)
        {
            int minPos = i;
            for(int j = i + 1; j < arrayMenu.length; j++)
            {
                if(arrayMenu[j] < arrayMenu[minPos]) minPos = j;
            }
            int temp = arrayMenu[i];
            arrayMenu[i] = arrayMenu[minPos];
            arrayMenu[minPos] = temp;
            System.out.print(temp + " ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Insertion Sort method.
     */
    public static void insertion(int n)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i < arrayMenu.length; i++)
        {
            int next = arrayMenu[i];
            int j = i;
            while(j > 0 && arrayMenu[j - 1] > next)
            {
                arrayMenu[j] = arrayMenu[j - 1];
                j--;
            }
            arrayMenu[j] = next;
            System.out.print(next + " ");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Quick Sort method.
     */
    public static void quick(int n)
    {
        int pivot = arrayMenu[0];
        int i = 0 - 1;
        int j = n + 1;
        while(i < j)
        {
            i++; while(arrayMenu[i] < pivot) i++;
            j++; while(arrayMenu[j] > pivot) j++;
            if(i < j)
            {
                int temp = arrayMenu[i];
                arrayMenu[i] = arrayMenu[j];
                arrayMenu[j] = temp;
                System.out.print(temp + " ");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Main method that allows user to input data. 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you wish to sort random integers? (Yes or No) ");
        String answer = in.next();
        String answer2 = answer.toLowerCase();

        do
        {
            /*Prompts for array length.*/
            System.out.println("How many random integers do you wish to sort?");
            int numInt = in.nextInt();
            /*Promps for sort selection choice.*/
            System.out.println("Select a sort to use: \n\t1)Selection\n\t2)Insertion\n\t3)Quick");
            String sort = in.next();
            String sort2 = sort.toLowerCase();
            if(sort2.equals("selection"))
            {
                selection(numInt);
            }
            else if(sort2.equals("insertion"))
            {
                insertion(numInt);
            }
            else if(sort2.equals("quick"))
            {
                quick(numInt);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You have entered the wrong input.");
            }
        } while(!answer2.equals("no"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `generator` is probably evaluating to null. Use a debugger and/or read the trace better.

Comment: You don't seem to understand what that word `static` you have all over the place means. You're calling static methods that reference a static array that you have never initialized.

Comment: pls paste the stacktrace...

Answer (score 1):

- Everything in your code is static. This means the constructor you wrote is never called, and the array has never been changed from its default value, `null`. Consider changing your constructor code to a static initialization block instead.
- `generator` is never set to anything, so it's null too and you can't call `nextInt` on it
- initializing the array is setting `arrayMenu[n]` instead of `arrayMenu[i]`

Answer (score 0):

When you call `insertion(numInt);`, method `public static void insertion(int n)` is called and then you are trying to do the for-loop like this `for(int i = 1; i < arrayMenu.length; i++)`

However, `arrayMenu` was not initialized, it is null. When you try to call a length, on null, you get NullPointerException.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a static constructor and initialize the size using a static int

```
//set parameter = n
public static int parameter;

static 
{ 
    arrayMenu = new int[parameter];
}
```